# pentaho CDE Class 'OUSER' was not found in current database

Tags: pentaho, orientdb, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am not able to preview pentaho CDE report or open CDE reports. I get following error:

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:506)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.handleStatus(OChannelBinary.java:461)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:146)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinaryAsynch.beginResponse(OChannelBinaryAsynch.java:57)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.beginResponse(OStorageRemote.java:1880)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1572)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:176)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.open(OStorageRemoteThread.java:70)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:89)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:119)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:49)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.java:44)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:44)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:20)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:57)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getResource(OResourcePool.java:68)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:74)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:59)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase.acquire(ODatabasePoolBase.java:115)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.getConnection(PersistenceEngine.java:166)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.classExists(PersistenceEngine.java:432)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.SimplePersistence.load(SimplePersistence.java:84)
    at org.pentaho.cdf.views.ViewsEngine.getView(ViewsEngine.java:100)
    at org.pentaho.cdf.context.ContextEngine.buildContextScript(ContextEngine.java:150)
    at org.pentaho.cdf.context.ContextEngine.getContext(ContextEngine.java:109)
    at org.pentaho.cdf.CdfContentGenerator.getContext(CdfContentGenerator.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.InterPluginCall.run(InterPluginCall.java:352)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.InterPluginCall.call(InterPluginCall.java:365)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.InterPluginCall.call(InterPluginCall.java:67)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.InterPluginBroker.getCdfContext(InterPluginBroker.java:50)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.api.RenderApi.render(RenderApi.java:115)
    at pt.webdetails.cdf.dd.DashboardDesignerContentGenerator.createContent(DashboardDesignerContentGenerator.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutput.generateContent(GeneratorStreamingOutput.java:229)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutput.write(GeneratorStreamingOutput.java:156)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.java:58)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(GeneratorStreamingOutputProvider.java:37)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSServlet.service(JAXRSServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.JAXRSServlet.service(JAXRSServlet.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(PentahoBasicProcessingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionPentahoSessionIntegrationFilter.java:265)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.WebappRootForwardingFilter.doFilter(WebappRootForwardingFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class 'OUSER' was not found in current database
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OChannelBinary.createException(OChannelBinary.java:508)
    ... 105 more
```

What error am I getting at orientDB? How to solve it?

Comment: Is that directly from sparkl?

Comment: @Codek it's from pentaho error log.

Comment: I mean is that when previewing within sparkl? Anyway what version? What did you do before it broke?

Comment: @Codek I am usually getting this error. I can preview report already made but not make new report. I can't preview report while I am making it since no components appear and I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update the ctools ?

Try removing the system/.orient folder and restarting the server.

Comment: OrientDb is an embedded document database we use for the Ctools. It keeps its data files on system/.orient. We recently updated the version we were using and the new version cannot process the old datafiles. Deleting the .orient folder resets the database.

Comment: Thank you ! Is there any way we could know what to change after update?

Comment: Not at the moment. Our ux guys are working on giving more visibility to our release notes. That should make it easier to know of breaking changes and what to do after updates